# phonegap 3.5.0 version warnings in opening project

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-build

I am a total newbie with phonegap and struggling last 2 days with it. I found many tutorials on how to install it, but none gave me the exact details so I combined them all to get it working. On some pages users write to install only phonegap, and not cordova and phonegap, and on other pages I see users write to install both. Since documentation is really bad, I am asking for info what is really correct?

I am not a native developer for Android, so I decided to use phonegap in combination with javascript, html, php, css. I created the project with this command in cmd:

```
C:\user\AndroidDev\vprojects\hello>phonegap create hello com.ex.hello "hello ved"
```

After that i added the platform with:

```
phonegap platform add android
```

I got a message:

```
debug:
BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 28 seconds
[phonegap] successfully compiled Android app
```

After that I opened my project in Eclipse (Android Project From Existing Code) and I got 28 warnings. I am not sure why and should this worry me, but it makes me uncomfortable. Warnings are:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unused") CordovaWebView.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 85 Java Problem
Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized    HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http  line 174    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaWebView.url is not used   CordovaWebView.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 88 Java Problem
Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")  HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/http  line 173    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaWebView.mResult is not used   CordovaWebView.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 106    Java Problem
The value of the local variable slot is not used    Spdy3.java  /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal/spdy  line 198    Java Problem
The import java.io.FileNotFoundException is never used  FileHelper.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 29 Java Problem
The import java.io.FileOutputStream is never used   FileHelper.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 30 Java Problem
The import java.io.OutputStream is never used   FileHelper.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 33 Java Problem
The import java.nio.charset.Charset is never used   FileHelper.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 34 Java Problem
The import android.widget.ImageView is never used   CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 55 Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaActivity.lastRequestCode is not used  CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 138    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaActivity.lastResponseCode is not used CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 144    Java Problem
The constructor WebView(Context, AttributeSet, int, boolean) is deprecated  CordovaWebView.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 205    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaActivity.LOG_TAG is not used  CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 148    Java Problem
Dead code   CordovaWebViewClient.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 129    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaActivity.responseCode is not used CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 140    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaActivity.lastIntent is not used   CordovaActivity.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 142    Java Problem
The import android.webkit.WebResourceResponse is never used CordovaWebViewClient.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 42 Java Problem
Dead code   CordovaWebViewClient.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 129    Java Problem
The value of the local variable serverProtocols is not used Platform.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal   line 359    Java Problem
The import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream is never used   CordovaWebViewClient.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 21 Java Problem
List is a raw type. References to generic type List<E> should be parameterized  Platform.java   /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp/internal   line 359    Java Problem
The value of the field CordovaChromeClient.LOG_TAG is not used  CordovaChromeClient.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 62 Java Problem
The method updateQuota(long) from the type WebStorage.QuotaUpdater is deprecated    CordovaChromeClient.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 294    Java Problem
The type WebStorage.QuotaUpdater is deprecated  CordovaChromeClient.java    /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 291    Java Problem
Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")    FileHelper.java /helloved-CordovaLib/src/org/apache/cordova line 50 Java Problem
Resource leak: 'snapshot' is never closed   HttpResponseCache.java  /helloved-CordovaLib/src/com/squareup/okhttp    line 272    Java Problem
```

[image]

Any advice would really help me or any info, are this warnings something that should worry me or is there  way to avoid them? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I don't think there is anything to worry about these wornings.